# MYSQL Inner join the table itself based on certain conditions to show either all, or none

Tags: mysql

Consider the tables:

```
table
no     |    date
--------------------------------
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
2      | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
2      | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
2      | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

What is the most efficient self-join query I can make, in order to produce the records that returns only the first 3 records (no. = 1) considering the condition is that the date must fall before 2016.

For instance, document no.2 will not show at all, because one of its date is > 2016, however document no.1 will show for all 3 records, because all 3 dates are < 2016

I tried the following:

```
SELECT a.no, a.date 
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON b.no = a.no AND b.date < '2016' --pseudocode for date comparison
```

However, the returned results are

```
no     |    date
--------------------------------
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
1      | 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
2      | 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I reject the premise of the question, because you have no way of uniquely identifying rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's are couple of ways of doing it without even using `JOIN`! Here's one:

```
select * from tbl 
where `no` not in
(
    select `no` from tbl
    where `date` >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
)
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this method instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the list of id's that should return and then use the self join as below:

```
select b.*
from table b
join (select id from table group by id having year(max(date)) <2016) x
on (a.no = x.no);
```

Comment: Is there a way to not use sub-queries at all, as it gradually decreases performance if the table size increases.

Comment: @NewbieCoder As a generalization about subqueries, that's simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT no, max(date) as max_date FROM table
    GROUP BY no
    HAVING max_date < '2016-01-01'
) t2

ON t1.no = t2.no
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand something but from your requirements - you don't need self-join.

> > For instance, document no.2 will not show at all, because one of its date is > 2016, however document no.1 will show for all 3 records, because all 3 dates are < 2016

You need  anti-join.

```
SELECT a.no, a.date 
FROM table A 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM table B 
        WHERE  
           B.no = A.no 
           AND B.date < DATE('2016-01-01')
    )
```